# Using induction to prove a sequence is always less than a given number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> Let $f(1)=2$ and $f(n+1)=\sqrt{3+f(n)}$. Prove that $f(n)<2.4$ for all $n\ge 1$.

I established a base case when $n=1$ and then moved on to the inductive step by assuming the statement is true for some $k \in\mathbb N$. I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: How much is $\sqrt{5.4}$ ?

Comment: approximately 2.3238, so $sqrt(5.4)<2.4$

Comment: This is the crux of the not-so-hard proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from $f(n) < 2.4$
$$3 + f(n) < 3+2.4$$
$$\sqrt{3+f(n)} < \sqrt{5.4}$$
$$f(n+1)<2.32 <2.4$$

Comment: So you did this problem without using induction?

Comment: @user3699546: what makes you think that there is no induction here ?

Comment: This is using your induction hypothesis, where $f(n) < 2.4$ for some $n≥1$

Comment: I thought after the inductive step we are supposed to let $n=k+1$. I see now that you did the same thing, but you didn't change variables.

Comment: Basically, when doing proof by induction, first you assume that $P(k)$ is true for some $k≥1$. Then, you show that $P(k+1)$ is true by using your prior assumption (induction hypothesis). This is sufficient to show that the statement is true for all $n≥1$

Comment: Something must be wrong with the way many kids learn induction: if you don't *specifically* write $\;n= k\implies n= k+1\;$ or the other way around, they get lost.

Comment: @Joshua Don't forget the base case. @ Timbuc. Seems more of a general problem with regard to seing variables as exchangeable symbols. School kids don't learn that $f(\text{tree}) = \text{tree}^2$ is the same statement as $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: oh yeah! i forgot. so first you prove that the base case is true, in this case $f(1)<2<2.4$ which means that $f(1)$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

1. $f(1)=2<2.4$.
2. $f(n)<2.4\implies f(n+1)=\sqrt{3+f(n)}<\sqrt{5.4}<2.4.$

So $f(1)<2.4\implies f(2)<2.4\implies f(3)<2.4\implies f(4)<2.4\implies f(5)<2.4\implies \cdots$

---

It is interesting to note that if the sequence converges, it will converge to $f$ such that $f=\sqrt{3+f}$, or $f^2-f-3=0$.

$$f=(\sqrt{13}+1)/2\approx2.30277563773\cdots$$